# Download file from server to local directory using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am not sure if I am understanding this correctly. Where should the data set that I want to download be in RStudio server?  I do not want to deploy yet, so I am not using the Shiny server, but I want to use the download functionality and save the data set as a file in a local directory.

I have uploaded a file using Shiny fileInput and I have saved the file using copy.file(). I was told that the uploaded file is saved to the server. The file is called 0.tsv.  Afterwards, I read that file and download it.  The GUI works, but the file doe not get written to a file and saved to the local directory. My question is: is there any thing missing in my approach?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('File download'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                  choices = c("data")),
      radioButtons("filetype", "File type:",
                   choices = c( "tsv")),
      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('table')
    )
  )
)



function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    # Fetch the appropriate data object, depending on the value
    # of input$dataset.
    data <- read.table("home/user/0.tsv")
    switch(input$dataset,
           "data" = data)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # downloadHandler() takes two arguments, both functions.
  # The content function is passed a filename as an argument, and
  #   it should write out data to that filename.
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    # This function returns a string which tells the client
    # browser what name to use when saving the file.
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, input$filetype, sep = ".")
    },

    # This function should write data to a file given to it by
    # the argument 'file'.
    content = function(file) {
      sep <- switch(input$filetype, "tsv" = "\t")

      # Write to a file specified by the 'file' argument
      write.table(datasetInput(), file, sep = sep,
                  row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel('File download'),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                      choices = c("data")),
          radioButtons("filetype", "File type:",
                       choices = c( "tsv")),
          downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('table')
        )
      )
    )



    function(input, output) {
      datasetInput <- reactive({
        # Fetch the appropriate data object, depending on the value
        # of input$dataset.
        data <- read.table("home/user/0.tsv")
        switch(input$dataset,
               "data" = data)
      })

      output$table <- renderTable({
        datasetInput()
      })

      # downloadHandler() takes two arguments, both functions.
      # The content function is passed a filename as an argument, and
      #   it should write out data to that filename.
      output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

        # This function returns a string which tells the client
        # browser what name to use when saving the file.
        filename = function() {
          paste(input$dataset, input$filetype, sep = ".")
        },

        # This function should write data to a file given to it by
        # the argument 'file'.
        content = function(file) {
          sep <- switch(input$filetype, "tsv" = "\t")

          # Write to a file specified by the 'file' argument
          write.table(datasetInput(), file, sep = sep,
                      row.names = FALSE)
        }
      )
    }


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Did you try downloading it from R Studio's inbuilt browser? Try running the app in a web browser and download it. I guess your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your response.  Below is the correct way to do it.  This works fine.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "params" = params)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({ 
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.table(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}
```